# How to return each line of a text file using a recursive function?

Tags: python, function, loops, recursion, functional-programming

I am trying to return each line of html.txt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
```

My current code is this:

```
def line_out(file):
    if len(file) == 1:
        exit()
    for lineno, line in enumerate(file):
        if lineno == 1:
                data = line
                del file[lineno]
                return data, (line_out(file))

with open('html.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    file = f.readlines()
    print(line_out(file))
```

My logic is: I will iterate through each line of the file by enumerating it and deleting each line I have returned/passed, then call the function with the new and smaller file until there is only one line left in that file.

When I print this function, it does not return each line.
I desire:

```
'<!DOCTYPE html>'
'<html lang="en" dir="ltr">'
'<head>'
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this recursively? It seems tailor-made for an iterative solution. Why don't you just iterate over the lines and print them one by one?

Comment: `f.readlines` already returns a list of all the lines. In theory, I could see the point of passing `f` itself to `line_out`, but recursion is just an expensive and limited way (in Python) in doing the same thing `readlines` already does.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the list of lines.

```py
with open(filepath, ‘r’) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line_no, content in enumerate(lines):
        print(f”{line_no}: {content}”)
```

This will return:

```
1: <!DOCTYPE html>
2: <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
3: <head>
```

And you can of course remove the `{line_no}:` portion if you want just the content printed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using recursion on the list of lines returned by f.readlines(), not on the stream descriptor itself (f).

```python
# make recursion on _open_ stream
def line_out_f(f):
    line=f.readline()
    if line=='':
        return []
    else:
        return [line]+line_out_f(f)

# 'Initial call'
with open('draft.py') as f:
    lines=line_out_f(f)
# further processing
for line_no, content in enumerate(lines):
    print(f'{line_no}: {content}')
```